# Windows 10 Applications development

Tags: wpf, windows-10

How is it possible to create applications like the ones in windows 10? I mean the navigation drawer, the back button in the title bar, the title bar color... etc
For example the "Calculator" app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 store apps are made by Universal Windows Platform (UWP). You need Windows 10 SDK and Visual Studio 2015. See more at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/getstarted.